# How to get all matching text of IN operator in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, in-operator

To be clear, here is the scenario: I am executing a query like the following:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE uid IN ( 1, 3, 5, 8, 23, 4, 589 ... )`

The list of `uid`s is coming from the user.

Is there a way to get all matching `uid`s in the list using SQL?

I am looking for Oracle SQL syntax but I also want to know the syntax for common database system.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I want to get *ALL MATCHING* `uid`s. For example, in the table there is no record that has a uid `8` and `23`, the output should be 1, 3, 5, 4, 589 ...

Comment: Your question is unclear, because the query you wrote seems to be exactly what you're asking for. Please add sample input and desired output.

Comment: I think what was asked in question is like all results from `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE uid IN ( 1, 3, 5, 8, 23, 4, 589 ... )` union `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE uid like '1%'` union `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE uid  like '3%'` so on. @JCA_Amellar am I correct?

Comment: Simplify (shorten IN list), add sample table data and also specify the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: your select do that ,what are you looking about

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get all matching uids in the list using SQL?

Yes, use your query but just get the `uid` column. If you do not want repeats then use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid
FROM   table_name
WHERE  uid IN ( 1, 3, 5, 8, 23, 4, 589 ... )
```

If you want it in a comma delimited list:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( uid, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY uid ) AS uids
FROM   table_name
WHERE  uid IN ( 1, 3, 5, 8, 23, 4, 589 ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure I understood correctly your question.
If you want to know, given a list of values, what are the one in the table and what are not, you can try this; you need to answer the values you are looking for in a temp table (or a select union clause or something like that) and then do a left join with your table (TX here is your table).  THIS SCRIPT IS FOR MSSQL TO GIVE YOU THE IDEA.  IT SHOULD BE EASY TO CONVERT THEM FOR ORACLE, IF THIS SOLUTION IS WHAT YOU WHERE ASKING (IT'S WAS NOT CLEAR FROM YOUR QUESTION).

```
CREATE TABLE TX (UID INT)
INSERT INTO TX VALUES (1),(5),(4)

CREATE TABLE TEMP1 (ID_VAL INT)
INSERT INTO TEMP1 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 589 

SELECT * FROM TEMP1

SELECT * 
FROM TEMP1
LEFT JOIN TX ON TEMP1.ID_VAL = TX.UID
```

Output:

```
ID_VAL      UID
----------- -----------
1           1
3           NULL
5           5
8           NULL
23          NULL
4           4
589         NULL
```

Comment: Your DML statements are not valid Oracle syntax.